# Request: reportPathPattern configuration property required

Tags: automated-tests, report, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I would like to request a "reportPathPattern" configuration property similar to the screenshotPathPattern property with Path Pattern Placeholder support.
This is so I can specify a custom pattern to compose the report file's relative path and name.

Comment: Most of path patterns are designed for work in the test context. 
Could you please provide resolved path examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for sharing your idea. You can track the status of this request in this thread:

[[PathPattern] Allow pathPatterns to be used with reporter path in config / CLI](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3417)